# Выключить музыку на будильник. AlarmManager cancel()

Tags: java, android

```
AlarmManager am;
Intent intent1;
PendingIntent pIntent1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
}

public void onClick1(View view) {
    intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Receiver.class);

    pIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, pIntent1);
}
public void onClick2(View view) {
    am.cancel(pIntent1);
}

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.a).start();
    }
}
```

После нажатия первой кнопки включатся музыка по AlarmManager.
Вопрос, как выключить запущенную музыку при помощи второй кнопки?
Метод cancel() не помогает в данном случае.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlarmManager am;
Intent intent1;
PendingIntent pIntent1;
protected static   MediaPlayer mPl;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    mPl=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.a);
}

public void onClick1(View view) {
    intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Receiver.class);

    pIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, pIntent1);
}
public void onClick2(View view) {
    mPl.pause();
}

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        MainActivity.mPl.start();
    }
}
```